# beforeAction() should be compatible with yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action)

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am working on a project and it is working fine on live server and on my local. but when i upload it on another server it gives me error of 
beforeAction() should be compatible with yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action).

I set up all the needed things on the server.

But When i login to my project on new server it gives me blank page with no error. And when i access inner pages(pages after login) it gives me error that 
beforeAction() should be compatible with yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action).

I cant understand actual problem and **i go through all the related answer given by this error but i can't find the exact answer.**

This is my beforeAction Function

```
public function beforeAction() {

    if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest) {
        $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('auth/login'));
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you override methods you need to use the same signature. Add the `$action` argument. Also it's good habit to check parent's results first in before* kind of methods:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest) {
            $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('auth/login'));
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Last thing here - it's better to use [access filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#access-control-filter) for this.

Comment: it still gives me blank page

Comment: Let me make it clear - you have added `$action` in this `beforeAction` signature and it still gives you error about exactly this `beforeAction` being incompatible with `yii\web\Controller::beforeAction($action)`?

Comment: Weird... Could you paste code of your controller together with logged error stack to pastebin.com and show us?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function beforeAction($action)
    { 
        ....
    }
```

pass $action in beforeAction method

Comment: I think its your php version problem - which php version do u use?

Comment: i am using php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You missed parameter which is required as per its definition in \yii\base\Controller.

Try this.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    parent::beforeAction($action);

    if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest)
    {
        $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('auth/login'));
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```